# Protect row based on value of another cell Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where I need to protect part of a row based on the value of another cell in that same row.

Sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EWJ22xU5LuInU78J8iX8rKMt2QvLy-HIVx6Wu58kcOw/edit?usp=sharing

I need to protect a row from col H:W when col AC is FALSE.
The values of col AC are created by a formula that analyzes the other cells of the row, it's not manually input.
If the value then changes back to TRUE, then I need it to be unprotected.
The rows that need protection aren't always all together.

I found a script that seems to do what I need, and other people said it worked for them, but I can't get it to work.
When the fuction is executed, nothing happens.

If posible, i would need to set certain rows and columns that should always be completely protected (row 1:2, col A, col X:AD).

```
/**
* Write-protects cells in rows when a magic value appears in a column.
* The account who runs the script retains edit rights to the cells.
* The cells are write-protected for others accounts.
*
* To take this script into use:
* 
*  - take a backup of your spreadsheet through File > Make a copy
*  - select all the text in this script, starting at the first "/**"
*    line above, and ending at the last "}"
*  - copy the script to the clipboard with Control+C (on a Mac, ⌘C)
*  - open the spreadsheet where you want to use the function
*  - choose Tools > Script editor > Blank (this opens a new tab)
*  - if you see just the 'function myFunction() {}' placeholder, press
*    Control+A (on a Mac, ⌘A), followed by Control+V (⌘V) to paste
*    the script in
*  - otherwise, choose File > New > Script file, then press
*    Control+A (⌘A) followed by Control+V (⌘V) to paste the script in
*  - modify the settings under "START modifiable parameters" as necessary
*  - press Control+S (⌘S) to save the script
*  - when prompted, name the project 'Write protect rows'
*  - to make the script run automatically when the spreadsheet is edited,
*    choose Edit > Current project's triggers > + Add Trigger >
*    writeProtectRows > on edit > Save
*  - when prompted, click Review Permissions > choose account > Advanced > 
*    Go to Protect rows > Allow (you only need to do this once)
*  - close the script editor tab and go back to the spreadsheet tab
*  - the script will run automatically when you edit a cell
*
* @see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/51506047?msgid=51933512
* @OnlyCurrentDoc
* @param {Object} e The event object.
*/
function writeProtectRows(e) {
  // version 1.2.1, written by --Hyde, 30 October 2020
  //  - add magicValue.unprotectRow
  // version 1.2, written by --Hyde, 9 June 2020
  //  - modify the script to work on edit
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/51506047?msgid=51933512
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 22 January 2019
  //  - protect certain columns always, in addition to protecting rows with dates that are in the past
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 21 January 2019
  //  - initial version
  //  - see https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/CKm-mXVixVg/Am26oxvgFAAJ
  
  ////////////////////////////////
  // [START modifiable parameters]
  var columnsToProtect = ['Cortes!H3:W'];
  var magicColumn = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Cortes!AC3:AC');
  var magicValue = {
    protectRow: 'FALSE',
    unprotectRow: 'TRUE',
  }
  // [END modifiable parameters]
  ////////////////////////////////
  
  var sheet = magicColumn.getSheet();
  if (!e 
      || !e.range
      || (e.value !== magicValue.protectRow && e.value !== magicValue.unprotectRow)
      || e.range.columnStart !== magicColumn.getColumn()
      || e.range.getSheet().getName() !== sheet.getName()) {
    return;
  }
  var values = magicColumn.getDisplayValues();
  var rowStart = magicColumn.getRow();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  removeAllRangeProtections_(sheet);
  for (var row = 0, rangeFirstRow = 0, rangeLastRow = 0, rangeBeingConstructed = false, magicColumnHeight = values.length; row < magicColumnHeight; row++) {
    var protectCurrentRow = (values[row][0] === magicValue.protectRow);
    if (protectCurrentRow) {
      if (!rangeBeingConstructed) {
        rangeBeingConstructed = true;
        rangeFirstRow = row;
      }
      rangeLastRow = row;
    }
    if (!protectCurrentRow || row === magicColumnHeight) {
      if (rangeBeingConstructed) {
        rangeBeingConstructed = false;
        for (var columnsIndex = 0; columnsIndex < columnsToProtect.length; columnsIndex++) {
          var rowRange = sheet.getRange(rowStart + rangeFirstRow, 1, rangeLastRow - rangeFirstRow + 1, numColumns);
          var columnRange = sheet.getRange(columnsToProtect[columnsIndex]);
          var rowRangeObject = getRangeIntersection_(rowRange, columnRange);
          if (rowRangeObject) {
            protectRange_(rowRangeObject.range);
          }
        } // columnsIndex
      } // if
    } // if
  } // row
}

/**
* Write-protects a range.
* The account who runs the script retains edit rights to the range.
* The range is write-protected for others accounts.
*
* @param {Range} range The range to protect.
* @return {Range} The same range, for chaining.
*/
function protectRange_(range) {
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var protection = range.protect();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
  return range;
}

/**
* On the given sheet, removes all range protections that the current account has permission to edit.
*
* @param {Sheet} sheet The sheet where range protections are to be removed.
* @return {Sheet} The same sheet, for chaining.
*/
function removeAllRangeProtections_(sheet) { 
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
      protection.remove();
    }
  }
  return sheet;
}

/**
* Returns the intersection of two ranges as an object that contains a new range and its grid coordinates.
*
* @param {Range} range A spreadsheet range object.
* @param {Range} intersectingRange A spreadsheet range object that possibly overlaps range.
* @return {Object} The intersection of range and intersectingRange, or null if they do not overlap. The return object has these fields:
*                  range       A range that represents the intersection of range1 and intersectingRange.
*                  firstRow    The first row of the intersection.
*                  firstColumn The first column of the intersection.
*                  lastRow     The last row of the intersection.
*                  lastColumn  The last column of the intersection.
*                  numRows     The number of rows in the intersection.
*                  numColumns  The number of columns in the intersection.
*/
function getRangeIntersection_(range, intersectingRange) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 22 January 2019
  //  - initial version
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetId() !== intersectingRange.getSheet().getSheetId()) {
    return null;
  }
  var firstRow = Math.max(range.getRow(), intersectingRange.getRow());
  var lastRow = Math.min(range.getLastRow(), intersectingRange.getLastRow());
  if (firstRow > lastRow) {
    return null;
  }
  var firstColumn = Math.max(range.getColumn(), intersectingRange.getColumn());
  var lastColumn = Math.min(range.getLastColumn(), intersectingRange.getLastColumn());
  if (firstColumn > lastColumn) {
    return null;
  }
  return {
    range: range.getSheet().getRange(firstRow, firstColumn, lastRow - firstRow + 1, lastColumn - firstColumn + 1),
    firstRow: firstRow,
    firstColumn: firstColumn,
    lastRow: lastRow,
    lastColumn: lastColumn,
    numRows: lastRow - firstRow + 1,
    numColumns: lastColumn - firstColumn + 1
  };
}
```

Comment: Hi there @AgustinaBotasMay! I don't understand where you need help, could you please clarify that? The `protectRange_` function of your code can be used to protect a range, why doesn't it work in your scenario?

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron I don't know why it doesn't work, I know very little coding, most of it from piecing together different bits I found on the internet. It doesn't give an error when it runs, on the execution loggs it shows as completed, but it doesn´t create the protections it should. The script just starts and ends without doing anything. With the basic knolege I have I looked it over but I can't find any mistake that would cause that.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your main goal is:

> I need to protect a row from col H:W when col AC is FALSE. *(…)* If the
> value then changes back to TRUE, then I need it to be unprotected.

If that is your goal, and you aren't obligated to use the script on your question, then you can use a simpler approach. You only need to evaluate the boolean cell, and if it's `TRUE` then you can use the `protectRange_` function. Otherwise if it's `FALSE` you can use `removeAllRangeProtections_`. You can evaluate the range with [`Range.getValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue). To protect/unprotect the row you can just reuse the script in your question. To make this operation run by itself, you can set up an [`onEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 29 && e.range.getValue() == true) {
    protectRange_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), 8,
      1, 16));
  } else if (e.range.getColumn() == 29 && e.range.getValue() == false) {
    removeAllRangeProtections_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet());
  }
}

function protectRange_(range) {
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var protection = range.protect();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
  return range;
}

function removeAllRangeProtections_(sheet) {
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
      protection.remove();
    }
  }
  return sheet;
}
```

This approach reuses two of the functions that you provided, `protectRange_` and `removeAllRangeProtections_`, both of which make an intensive use of the [Protection Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection). I strongly advise you to check that class and familiarise yourself with the methods used in your functions. Lastly please be aware that while `protectRange_` protects a certain range, `removeAllRangeProtections_` removes any protections.